# Localizing html content in vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

So I have been using v-html tag to render the html in my vue pages.
But I encountered a string which was a proper html file and it contained text kind of like this:

```
<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
....
<style>
</style>
</head>

<body style="....">
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is, I have the v-html on a div, but this code starts affecting the whole page and adds its styling to the whole page and not only to that specific div.

I tried adding "scope" to the style tags but it did not work. Maybe because there's also a style inline tag on body?

I need to find a way to make the html affect only on the div it is on, and not the whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would probably be to have a better control over the HTML added using `v-html`. I would suggest to parse it before and keep only the `<body>` tag. You could do it using a regex, but it would be easier using a dom parser lib. Example with [DomParser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-parser):

```js
const DomParser = require("dom-parser");
const parser = new DomParser();

export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    html() {
      const rawHtml = "<html><body><div>test</div></body></html>"; // This data should come from your server
      const dom = parser.parseFromString(rawHtml);
      return dom.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that it is an oversimplified solution as it does not handle the case where there is no `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be very careful when using external HTML with `v-html` as it can make your site vulnerable to various sorts of attacks ([see Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html)).

Now if you trust the HTML source, other problem is how to embed it without affecting your own side. There is special element for this case, `<iframe>` - it is not without risk and you should definitely read a bit on how to make it safe but it should solve your problem because is "sandbox" external HMTL so it does not affect your site.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Other_embedding_technologies